# Prove $(x^2 + xy + y^2)^2$ divides $(x + y)^{6n + 1} - x^{6n + 1} - y^{6n + 1}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

As stated in the title, I want to show the (bivariate) polynomial $g(x, y) = (x^2 + xy + y^2)^2$ divides the polynomial $f(x, y) = (x + y)^{6n + 1} - x^{6n + 1} - y^{6n + 1}$, where $n \geq 0$.

Naturally, I resorted induction. For $n = 1$, $f(x, y) = 7xy(x + y)g(x, y)$. From $n$ to $n + 1$,
I am only able to show that $x^2 + xy + y^2$ is a factor of $f(x, y)$. Is there any trick I am missing?

Comment: Maybe try showing $(x^3-y^3)^2$ divides $(x-y)^2 \cdot RHS$? It might suffice to consider $y= e^{2\pi  i k /3} x,$ $k=0,1,2$ and then show multiplicity?

Comment: @Integrand Sounds a promising track!

Comment: It suffices to take $y=1$ because the polynomials are homogeneous.

Comment: @lhf Can you explain why can we take $y=1$? The problem becomes trivial after that by checking that the non-real cube roots of unity are the factors of $f$ with multiplicity 2 by plugging them in $f$ and its derivative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key insight is that suffices to take $y=1$ because the polynomials are homogeneous. The precise details are below.

Write $z=x/y$.

Then $x^2 + xy + y^2 = y^2(z^2+z+1)$ and $(x + y)^{6n + 1} - x^{6n + 1} - y^{6n + 1}=y^{6n + 1}((z + 1)^{6n + 1} - z^{6n + 1} - 1)$.

Thus, it suffices to prove that $(z^2+z+1)^2$ divides $(z + 1)^{6n + 1} - z^{6n + 1} - 1$.

Let $h(z)=z^2+z+1$.

We have $(z+1)^{6n} \equiv 1 \bmod h(z)$.
because $(z+1)^6=(z^4 + 5 z^3 + 9 z^2 + 6 z)h(z)+1$.

We have $z^{6n} \equiv 1 \bmod h(z)$
because $z^3= (z-1)h(z)+1$.

Therefore,
$f(z)=(z + 1)^{6n + 1} - z^{6n + 1} - 1 \equiv (z+1) -z -1 = 0 \bmod h(z)$

Now
$f'(z)=(6n+1)((z + 1)^{6n} - z^{6n}) \equiv (6n+1)(1-1) = 0\bmod h(z)$

Therefore, $h$ divides both $f$ and $f'$, and so $h^2$ divides $f$.

All this can be done exactly the same without introducing $z$ but it is easy only in hindsight.

Comment: Nice skill. Thanks a lot.

Comment: One more question. "$h$ divides both $f$ and $f'$, and so $h^2$ divides $f$". Is it generally true or it rests on $(h, h') = 1$?

Comment: @Zhanxiong, it relies on $(h, h') = 1$.

Comment: Thanks for your confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

Let $ y = k $ = constant and let $f(x)= (x+k)^{6n+1} - x^{6n+1}-k^{6n+1}$. We know that
$x^2 + xk + k^2= (x-kw)(x-kw^2)$ where $w$, $w^2$  are cube roots of unity. If we put $x=kw $ and $kw^2$ in $f(x)$, it gives the value $0$. Therefore $(x-kw)(x-kw^2)$ divides $f(x)$ .  $\frac{df(x)}{dx}$ = $(6n+1)((x+k)^{6n} -x^{6n})$. Putting $x=kw $ and $kw^2$ in this expression we also get $0$. Therefore  $(x-kw)(x-kw^2)$ divides both $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$. Therefore ${((x-kw)(x-kw^2))}^2$ divides $f(x)$ that is $(x^2 + xk + k^2)^2$ divides $f(x)$  . By varying $k$ we get that it is true for all values of $y$.